# Is there a way to access all the values of objects inside the prototype function?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, prototype

I'm learning javascript and I came across this situation, that I am not able to figure out by myself.

Let's say I created a constructor function like this which is trying to mimic an array:

```js
// constructor function
function myArray() {
    for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        this[`${i}`] = arguments[i];
    }
    this.length = arguments.length;
}

let fruits = new myArray('apple', 'mangoes', 'banana');
```

This will create Object `fruits` like this:

```
myArray {0: "apple", 1: "mangoes", 2: "banana", length: 3}
0: "apple"
1: "mangoes"
2: "banana"
length: 3
```

Now, I want to create my own function for `myArray` that can access all the values of the `fruits` object so I can perform some operations with it. Like, `reverse` function for example:

```
myArray.prototype.reverse = function () {
    //how do i access all elements/values of friuts here?
};
```

I can set `this.args = arguments;` inside the constructor function
and access args inside the prototype function to do something with it.

But it is only limited to the original Object. If I add more elements to my object in the future by using another function, then it won't work as it is only taking args from the original object.
Is there a way to pass the current Object inside the prototype function?

EDIT:
As Tushar Shahi mentioned, we can implement reverse function by reversing the original argument. But how can we access the elements that are added to the object later. Here is the full code just so you guys can have a clear understanding.

```js
// constructor function
function myArray() {
  this.args = Array.from(arguments);
  for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    this[`${i}`] = arguments[i];
  }
  this.length = arguments.length;
}
let fruits = new myArray("apple", "mangoes", "banana");

// reverse function
myArray.prototype.reverse = function () {
  // reversing the arguments first then assigning values
  this.args = this.args.reverse();
  for (let i = 0; i < this.args.length; i++) {
    this[i] = this.args[i];
  }
  // but how do i access all elements/values of friuts here and not just the arguments?
}

// add/push function
myArray.prototype.add = function (a) {
  let index = this.length;
  this[index] = a;
  this.length++;
}

// pop function
myArray.prototype.pop = function (a) {
  let index = this.length - 1;
  delete this[index];
  this.length--;
}

fruits.add("orange"); // orange is added to fruits
fruits.add("pineapple"); // pineapple is added to fruits

console.log('fruits.reverse() ...', fruits.reverse());
console.log({ fruits }); // myArray {0: "banana", 1: "mangoes", 2: "apple", 3: "orange", 4: "pineapple", args: Array(3), length: 5}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

As you can see in the last console.log, I am able to reverse only 3 arguments that were passed originally but not the elements that were added later.
Pineapple should be the first fruit after reversing. So the question is
How can we access elements added later inside the reverse function? or
How can we access the current fruit object inside the reverse function?

Comment: Unrelated: You can replace `this[\`${i}\`]` with `this[i]`

Comment: `Object.keys(this)` will return an [array of the keys/properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) (noting that you have to deal with sparse arrays where there are missing indexes).

Comment: Using `this` will give you access to the object on which any prototype function is called on. What you need is a way to increment/decrement the `length` property when elements are added/removed from the object.

Comment: I appreciate the effort of learning the language from its very core. Unfortunately writing own `List`-like types which also should mimicry some of the array methods based on just/pure ECMA-3 constructor functions is the most painful adventure which mostly just confuses and frustrates not only the very beginner. Maybe for constructor function and prototype research you might come up with less complicated own types?

Comment: @mrsagar105 ... regarding your Q from the last edited example code. While `add`ing and `pop`ing one of cause needs to keep track of all the items by updating both the `args` property and the integer based `idx`-properties.

Comment: @mrsagar105 ... btw ... until now the *array-like* type you've come up with has the features of a `Stack` with the oddity of having a reversible stack precedence. As long as one only wants to `push`, `pop` and `reverse` the stack without the need of directly accessing its items one can provide a very clean solution to it.

Comment: @PeterSeliger Oh, i got it, so adding this line `this.args.push(a);` inside add function and `this.args.pop()` inside pop function should work.
It is working actually, thanks! But I think this will this is not making any sense, I am just complicating the code because what we are basically doing is creating an array and keeping track of it.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep a copy of your initial arguments as an array it should work.

`arguments` is an [array-like object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), not exactly an array. So that has to be converted.
Also, do not forget to reverse the `args` property itself. So it works when you use it multiple times.

```js
function myArray() {
    this.args = Array.from(arguments);
    for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        this[i] = arguments[i];
    }
    this.length = arguments.length;
}

let fruits = new myArray('apple', 'mangoes', 'banana');

myArray.prototype.reverse = function () {
    this.args = this.args.reverse();
    let j = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.args.length; i++) {
        this[i] = this.args[i];
    }
};

fruits.reverse();
fruits.reverse();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But is there a way we could access the current fruits object and not the original object only? If we add more elements to the object, the added elements will not be reversed as we are only selecting the arguments. I have updated the question.

Comment: @mrsagar105 ... how are you going to add more items?.. regardless of the implementation we are already very close to opening pandoras box.

Comment: @mrsagar105 ... besides from introducing a public accessible `args` property to any `myArray` instance, *Tushar's* approach is the only one that actually would save you from a lot of pain. But then the question arises, why would one not just want to use `Array` instances right away.

Comment: @PeterSeliger Thank you so much Peter for your comments. Actually, I am just learning javascript and trying to learn the possible ways. We could definitely use custom or inbuilt functions to reverse it but I was also wondering how javascript implemented the reverse function. I thought there might be an easy way to do this.
I have added a push/add function that will add to the fruits object. At the end of the question, I have updated it. Thanks!

Comment: Adding to what @PeterSeliger said regarding the use of simple arrays. If you create new prototype functions like add remove, make sure to update the args property in that function implementation. I can update my answer to do that but it is just a simple push or splice. If you do not want to use the args property you can write a code(which i think will be a little complex inside your reverse function) to access directly from the object properties.

Answer (score 1):

This code does not answer the OP's original question. It gets provided just in order to show to the OP, how a simple `Stack` abstraction actually could look like (something the OP's implementation does mimic which I was referring to in my last comment to the OP) ...

```js
function Stack() {
  const stack = Array.from(arguments);

  this.push = (...args) => stack.push(...args);
  this.pop = () => stack.pop();

  this.size = () => stack.length;
  this.reverse = () => Array.from(stack.reverse());
}
let fruits = new Stack("apple", "mango", "banana");

console.log(
  'fruits.push("orange", "kiwi") ...',
  fruits.push("orange", "kiwi")
);
console.log(
  'fruits.push("pineapple") ...',
  fruits.push("pineapple")
);
console.log(
  'fruits.reverse() ...',
  fruits.reverse()
);
console.log(
  'fruits.pop() ...',
  fruits.pop()
);
console.log(
  'fruits.pop() ...',
  fruits.pop()
);
console.log(
  'fruits.size() ...',
  fruits.size()
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I got your point now. Thank you so much for your effort!